# Problem installing phpstorm 7 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ide

I have been struggling with installing Phpstorm in Ubuntu 14.04 since I am new to Ubuntu. I have put [Phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) in my home directory. Here is the code I use after that to activate the software.

```
cd /path/Phpstorm/bin
chmod +x phpstorm.sh
./phpstorm.sh
```

And I get this error message. Can anyone help me with this?

```
[    443]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - No valid license found 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:115)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.g.bb.a(bb.java:107)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.start(MainImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:140)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
[    445]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - PhpStorm 8.0.1  Build #PS-138.2001.2328 
[    446]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - JDK: 1.6.0_33 
[    446]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[    446]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. 
[    446]  ERROR - nse.impl.GeneralLicenseManager - OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. You should install the JDK first:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

then try again to launch the PhpStorm from it's installation folder:

`./phpstorm.sh`